# WebKit control, HTTPS and peer certificate verification error

Tags: c#, ssl, webkit

Created C# project with [WebKit](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) control. HTTP Webpage are working just fine, but when I try to open HTTPS web page it throws error "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates".
Already tried Google, found that I must do this:

> Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBKIT_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS", "1");

It's not working, and I'm setting it before webkit control is initialized, even tried to place it as a first action in Main function in program.cs, still problem remains. Also tried to install certificate into trusted root.
I'm out of ideas how to solve it.

Comment: *"Google, found that I must do ... WEBKIT_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS"* - that's probably a bad idea. I think this would be a *really* good question if you attempted to fix the underlying problem rather than potentially breaking PKIX and tossing security out the window :)